# How to mksquashfs AUFS filesystem without '.wh..wh.' but including files whiteouts?

Tags: squashfs, aufs

I have an AUFS filesystem mounted in a live session and I want to use mksquashfs to compress it into a single file. In the root folder I have:

```
.wh..wh.orph/
.wh..wh.plnk/
dev/
etc/
home/
lib/
mnt/
root/
run/
tmp/
usr/
var/
.wh..wh.aufs
```

I don't want to include any of these `.wh..wh.` in the root folder, except that if the user has hard-deleted a file in one of the sub-folders I would like to keep their whiteouts in the mksquashfs. Example: use has deleted `/usr/bin/vim` so the file `aufsPath/usr/bin/.wh.vim` will be automatically created, and I want to keep it inside the mksquashfs.

So far I can either have everything (the whiteouts from both root and hard-deleted files) or everything but the whiteouts.

The command I'm using is this: `mksquashfs [aufsPath] [compressedFile.mksquash] -e .wh..wh.orph .wh..wh.plnk .wh..wh.aufs`.

If I remove `.wh..wh.aufs` from the command above, the hard-deleted whiteouts don't go into the mksquashfs file.

Comment: I dont know how to explain why removing the last `-e` item stops whiteouts from being saved, but note that whiteouts are all hard-links to `.wh..wh.aufs`; maybe that plays a role as a brief look at the source code seems to show sometimes it compares inode numbers when excluding. You might try adding option `-wildcards` as that makes `mksquashfs` work slightly differently in this case. Alternatively, you can always extend an existing squashfs image to add new files to it, so you could try using `find` to list the whiteout files, and running a second `mksquashfs` to add just this explicit list.